# Parameter is missing in props validation

Tags: reactjs

That's App.jsx

```
import './App.css'
import Pp from './Pp'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Pp parameter={"asdsd"} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

That's Pp.jsx

```
export default function Pp({ parameter }) {
  return (
    <h1>{parameter}</h1>
  )
}
```

I get the "parameter is missing in props validation" error.

I talked to the chatgpt around like a freaking hour, but I didn't get any valid result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from your linter, you need to define propTypes:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function Pp({ parameter }) {
  return (
    <h1>{parameter}</h1>
  )
}

Pp.propTypes = {
  parameter: PropTypes.string
};
```

Comment: Where do you see the need for this?  Nevermind that `prop-types` is an external library that OP would need to install ..  OP should be able to do what he is asking with nothing but native react hooks `useState` specifically -- and declaring constants.  Why so complicated for such a 101 level task?

Comment: Your answer suffers from the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) --  That is, coming up with a solution that fits a specific problem --  Without realizing that the problem is the question itself.  OP doesn't need to redeclare his parameter as a string with an external library.. He needs to declare it, and set it, correctly in the first place.

Comment: what works, but don't really understand why it doesn't work without it, because in all tutorials i've watched, nobody used that

Comment: It's from react's docs, https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html and in the new docs, https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#static-proptypes

Comment: @Nikolai -- This is because it's not required unless you want to pass a literal string, which most don't/won't do .. See my answer .. It is textbook 101 level.  Build a constant and pass it.  Passing literals is just ..  messy coding.  Just because you **can**, doesn't mean you *should*

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare your parameter and pass it to your Pp Component. You will see that we can pass the string `Foo` to our `Pp` component.  Furthermore .. We can control the state and **SET** it to `Bar` if and when we wish.

Sending literals through to components without controlling them in a State/hook as in Joe Lissner's answer (unless for some reason you need to hard-code the value ... But then why pass it?) is just messy coding.

```
import './App.css'
import Pp from './Pp'
import React, {useState} from "react"; // ability to set states

export default function App() {
const [parameter, setParameter] = useState('Foo'); // Set parameter constant, and the ability to change it at will
  return (
    <div>
      <Pp 
         parameter={parameter} 
         setParameter={setParameter}    
     />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Pp.jsx

```
// Remember to "call" both parameters that you passed from App.js Component
export default function Pp({ parameter, setParameter }) {

  // You can now use setParameter('Bar') anywhere to set your parameter as well 
  // Since it is stored in a state and passed to this Component
  // setParameter('Bar'); // Uncomment this line for an example
  return (
    <h1>{parameter}</h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: I have created an App -- tested and confirmed this code works -- Please explain your downvote, whoever you are.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the quotes when you're passing the props in the PP component in your App.jsx file

Comment: what do you mean, i send the string as a parameter, if i remove them it's absolutely invalid code

Comment: Remove the double quotes around asdsd. I don't have a laptop on me to show you. Something like;  <Pp paramater={asdsd} />

Comment: Make a state variable using useState and initialize the string over there.
And then pass that variable parameter={here...} without quotes.

Comment: @RobinMuhia254 if you do that, it will be looking for a constant **named** `asdsd` -- Which there is none, so the code will fail.  He needs to set a constant with the **value** `asdsd` and **pass** it.

Comment: Agreed..I didn't even notice he never declared the variable in the first place